Node Runtime Version Reversion from 20.x to 14.x
Problem Description:
I have a React project with a backend set up using AWS Amplify environment. In the backend, I utilize various resources such as Auth, Host, Function, and API. Initially, all resources were configured with the runtime environment set to node14.x. However, upon attempting to deploy using the Amplify CLI, I encountered an error prompting me to use node20.x instead. To resolve this, I updated the CloudFormation templates for all functions to use node20.x and also adjusted the Auth CloudFormation template under the build folder accordingly.
Current Issue:
After making these adjustments, when I execute amplify push, I encounter an error message stating that "UserPoolClientLambda", "HostedUIProvidersCustomResource", and "HostedUICustomResource" are still configured with the nodejs14.x runtime. Despite updating the runtime to 20.x in the CloudFormation templates, it seems that upon executing amplify push, the runtime configuration for these resources in the Auth section reverts back to 14.x.
Steps Taken:

Updated all Function CloudFormation templates to use node20.x.
Modified the Auth CloudFormation template under the build folder to reflect node20.x runtime.
Executed amplify push, resulting in errors indicating nodejs14.x runtime for specific resources under Auth.

Request for Assistance:
I seek guidance on how to ensure that the runtime configuration for Auth resources, particularly "UserPoolClientLambda", "HostedUIProvidersCustomResource", and "HostedUICustomResource," remains set to node20.x after executing amplify push. Additionally, any insights into why the runtime configuration appears to revert back to nodejs14.x specifically for these Auth-related resources would be greatly appreciated.
Thank you for your assistance.
